# Converting query from Oracle to hive

Tags: mysql, oracle, hive

How to convert below query of `oracle to hive?`

```
Select * from table1, table2 where table1.column1=table2.column1 
and table1.Column2=table2.column2;
```

**Column1, Column2** are join columns, hence names are same.

Will it work in hive **without making any changes**?

I changed it as below.

```
Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1 
and table1.Column2=table2.column2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to run **both queries** from Hive.

```
hive> Select * from table1, table2 where table1.column1=table2.column1 
      and table1. Column2=table2.column2
```

For more detailed information regards how the join happens behind the scenes check out **Explain plan** for both queries.

**Explain Plan:**

```
hive> explain Select * from table1, table2 where table1.column1=table2.column1 
    and table1. Column2=table2.column2;
```